# Thunderbird: how to back up everything, including attachments

Tags: email, backup, thunderbird, gmail, archiving

I want to create a backup snapshot of everything I have on Gmail (preferably including Contacts), in a form that is later browseable by Thunderbird. This should also include all attachments. The result should be a file or a folder, which I can then copy onto an external drive and import later.

After installing Thunderbird, it correctly recognizes all emails in my Gmail, but, as far as I can see, it only downloads the message headers, no content. In the folder properties, the checkbox "Select this folder for offline use is checked".

Is this possible?

EDIT: I'm still checking, but it seems that, in time, Thunderbird actually did sync my mail into the local folder. It wasn't very obvious that it was in the process, though. The answers are very helpful, still.

Comment: Detailed instructions are at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail

Comment: Be sure to also read https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization

Comment: And https://thunderbirdtweaks.blogspot.com/2014/04/backup-up-gmail-with-thunderbird.html

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, I've already queued up a Google Takeout download, I just wasn't sure how compatible it will be with clients, thanks for the last link!

Comment: I have read the other links, but I have a feeling that my Thunderbird is not syncing or not synced up, even though the folders are marked as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy! Just copy the entire profile, which in Windows is `\User\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\????????.default` (In Linux, it will be in your Home folder in `.thunderbird`.). If your goals is to copy *only* GMail, and not other accounts, then the simplest way is to copy the whole profile and then delete other accounts in the `ImapMail` folder. Keep the .msf file as well as the GMail folder.

To save anything downloaded to local folders, also copy the `Mail` folder.

[image: Thunderbird mail folders, Windows]

*Location of mail folders for Yahoo account*.

Comment: This answer is OK, except the OP has indicated that he doesn't think his email is correctly synced ....

Comment: Is that the procedure used to back up the account? if it doesn't work for @Zubo, I'll delete it.